# Tangency point of two ellipses does not coincide for one of the ellipses

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, ellipse

The function below will calculate the tendency points of two ellipses including the cross points and the tangency points. I have two pictures which I have to retrieve the vanishing points from two ellipses plane of the car. The function works well for the first image but for the second image it gives me the wrong coordinates for the cross points and tangency points of the front wheel.

This is the function:

```matlab
function points = ellipsesPointsSelection( C1, H1, C2, H2)
    % this function takes into account two ellipses matrices and the
    % homographies to apply to them (rotation + translation) and returns 
    % the four tangency points of the two bitangent lines to the two ellipses
    
 
        syms l1 l2
        l = [l1; l2; 1];
        eqns = [l.'*inv(inv(H1).'*C1*inv(H1))*l == 0, l.'*inv(inv(H2).'*C2*inv(H2))*l == 0];
        vars = [l1 l2];
        [sol_l1, sol_l2] = vpasolve(eqns, vars);

        L = [double(sol_l1.'); double(sol_l2.'); ones(1,4)];

        X = (inv(H1).'*C1*inv(H1))\L;
        Y = (inv(H2).'*C2*inv(H2))\L;
        
        pt_tng_ul = X(:,1)'; % upper (u) point (pt) tangent (tng) to the left (l) ellipse
        pt_tng_ur = Y(:,1)';
        pt_tng_dr = Y(:,2)';
        pt_tng_dl = X(:,2)';
        
        pt_cross_ul = X(:,4)'; % upper (u) point (pt) tangent (tng) to the left (l) ellipse
        pt_cross_dl = X(:,3)';
        pt_cross_dr = Y(:,4)';
        pt_cross_ur = Y(:,3)';
        
        points = [  pt_tng_ul;
                    pt_tng_ur;
                    pt_tng_dr;
                    pt_tng_dl;
                    pt_cross_ul;
                    pt_cross_ur;
                    pt_cross_dr;
                    pt_cross_dl];
    end
```

I'm using the function like this in my main code:

```matlab
norm_matrix = diag([1, 1, 1]);% normalization off

H1 =  norm_matrix*H1; % normalized rototranslation
H2 =  norm_matrix*H2; % normalized rototranslation

ellipsesPoints = ellipsesPointsSelection(C1, H1, C2, H2);


H1_1 = norm_matrix*H1_1; % normalized rototranslation
H2_2 =  norm_matrix*H2_2; % normalized rototranslation


ellipsesPoints2 = ellipsesPointsSelection(C1_1, H1_1, C2_2, H2_2);
```

and the result for image1 is:

[image]

and the result for the second image tangency points is this one:

[image]

As you can see the tangency points for the front wheel are not correct. I tried to fix another ellipse for the front wheel of the second image and the parameters of C and H changed a little bit but still, tangency points are wrong. I appreciate your comments and opinions regarding this problem.

Comment: Are you able to add in the values of C and H you are using? And if possible the expected results? Thanks

Comment: feel like coordinate transformation is sliding. did you check well the calculation

Comment: Thanks for your comments simply i just tried to fix a better ellipse for the front rear of the second image with this algorithm [link](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33970-ellipse-detection-using-1d-hough-transform). so the problem this method is that depending of the max and min semi-major axis it will give you the best fit ellipse. the problem was the theta of the ellipse, which cause the miss matching of the tangency points for the front wheel. thanks, guys @YunusTemurlenk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ellipse detection technique is simply detecting the best fit ellipse by receiving the semi-major and semi-minor axis of the ellipses. and return and ellipse which:

```
x_c_1 = ellipse1_Front(1,1); % x position of the center of the image1 front wheel 
y_c_1 = ellipse1_Front(1,2); % y position of the center of the image1 front wheel 
semi_maj_1 = ellipse1_Front(1,3); % semi major axis of the image1 front wheel 
semi_min_1 = ellipse1_Front(1,4); % semi minor axis of the image1 front wheel 
theta1 = ellipse1_Front(1,5)*pi/180; % angle of the image1 front wheel
```

in my case, the fifth element of the ellipse which is the theta1 was problematic for the ellipsePointsSelection function. i tried to change the input parameter for ellipseDetection function it means changing the semi-major and semi-minor values and found a suitable ellipse which also has tangency points aligned on it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGWIW.jpg)